# Bootstrap 4 carousel hiding navbar-toggler

Tags: bootstrap-4

I experienced a few issues when trying to put a carousel on top of the page;

It seems to fit well, but when I switch to mobile, the navbar-toggler is behind the carousel;

I tried with z-index with the toggler to 1, but it doesn't work;

You can see the test page there:
http://next.brasseriedeschorre.be/

Thanks in advance...

Laurent Kreps

Comment: I found out that the target doesn't fit the id of the collapsable part; but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the way/problem;

it seems that I have to choose between navbar-dark or navbar-light (I used a navbar-trans that I wrote, but it seems insufficient).

Thanks to all